# I'm getting a System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to HPACK encode the headers error when using Azure B2C authentication in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using azure B2C in a C# (.net core mvc) web application for authentication. Last night I started receiving this error when running locally. This does not happen to any of the developers, and it does not happen in any of our published environments (QA / prod). I run the application, it brings me to the azure B2C login screen. I successfully authenticate and when it redirects back to my application from the azure B2C flow, I get a http protocol error. The console shows the error text as

> Failed to HPACK encode the headers

[azure B2C login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7PBx.png)

[protocol error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmSV2.png)

stack track:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to HPACK encode the headers.
       ---> System.Net.Http.HPack.HPackEncodingException: Failed to HPACK encode the headers.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.HPackHeaderWriter.EncodeHeadersCore(DynamicHPackEncoder hpackEncoder, Http2HeadersEnumerator headersEnumerator, Span`1 buffer, Boolean throwIfNoneEncoded, Int32& length)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2FrameWriter.FinishWritingHeaders(Int32 streamId, Int32 payloadLength, Boolean done)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2FrameWriter.WriteResponseHeaders(Int32 streamId, Int32 statusCode, Http2HeadersFrameFlags headerFrameFlags, HttpResponseHeaders headers)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2FrameWriter.WriteResponseHeaders(Int32 streamId, Int32 statusCode, Http2HeadersFrameFlags headerFrameFlags, HttpResponseHeaders headers)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2OutputProducer.WriteResponseHeaders(Int32 statusCode, String reasonPhrase, HttpResponseHeaders responseHeaders, Boolean autoChunk, Boolean appCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProduceStart(Boolean appCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.InitializeResponseAsync(Int32 firstWriteByteCount)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.FlushPipeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseStream.FlushAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.ResponseStreamWrapper.FlushAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.ScriptInjectionFilterStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.HttpResponseStreamWriter.FlushInternalAsync(Boolean flushEncoder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.HttpResponseStreamWriter.WriteAsyncAwaited(String value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Buffers.ViewBuffer.WriteToAsync(TextWriter writer, HtmlEncoder encoder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I was running the application as I always have, and expected it to login/authenticate as it always has.